# Store struct as string in redis

Tags: json, string, struct, go

As Redis only stores strings I would like to know how I can do the equivalent of Javascript's JSON.stringify using Go to convert a Struct into a string.

I have tried typecasting:

```
string(the_struct)
```

but this results in an error.

Comment: You can store objects in redis using [Hashes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#hashes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package can be used to easily convert a `struct` to JSON string and vice versa (parse a JSON string into a `struct`).

Simple example (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fZzKA5Yveh)):

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    p := Person{"Bob", 23}

    // Struct -> JSON
    data, err := json.Marshal(&p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))

    // JSON -> JSON
    var p2 Person
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &p2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", p2)
}
```

Output:

```
{"Name":"Bob","Age":23}
{Name:Bob Age:23}
```

#### Notes:

The fields of the `struct` must be exported (start them with capital letter), else the `json` package (which uses reflection) will not be able to read/write them.

You can also specify tags for the struct fields to control/fine tune the json marshaling/unmarshaling process, for example to change the names in the JSON text:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"years"`
}
```

With this change the output of the above application is the following:

```
{"name":"Bob","years":23}
{Name:Bob Age:23}
```

The documentation of the [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) function details the possibilities provided by the tags.

And by implementing the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interfaces you can fully customize the marshaling / unmarshaling process.

Also if your struct is not pre-defined (e.g. you don't know the fields in advance), you can use a `map[string]interface{}`. [See this answer for details and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860080/1705598).

Comment: @tommyd456 It is a byte slice (`[]byte`), basically the UTF-8 encoded data of the `string` representation.